# Search words with 'and' logical condition with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook Graph API I am trying to search for all public pages related with two or more words. I want the AND condition satisfied.

Trying to use a query like i.e.

**https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search?access_token=my_token&type=page&q=marziano+venusiano&limit=1000**

but it gives me empty data answer.

I've tried to use something suggested in old questions, but it seems to be not working any more.

What is the right syntax to use if one exist?

Comment: If you search *marziano* and *venusiano* together on facebook.com, it also returns no results for pages. So, where exactly is the problem?

Comment: You are right. I thing I am still in the weaken mood, sorry. I am going to delete this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is no page with these two words in the name. If you try *scuderia* and *ferrari*, the results look as desired:

```
/search?type=page&q=scuderia+ferrari
```

returns

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Scuderia Ferrari",
      "id": "500214176674878"
    },
    {
      "name": "Scuderia Ferrari",
      "id": "105467226153743"
    },
    {
      "name": "Scuderia Ferrari Club Prealpi Venete",
      "id": "342159749154826"
    },
    {
      "name": "Scuderia Ferrari Club Prato",
      "id": "1414918342093728"
    },
    {
      "name": "Scuderia Ferrari Club Zola Predosa",
      "id": "226860530777232"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MjQZD"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search?access_token=&pretty=0&q=scuderia+ferrari&type=page&limit=25&after=MjQZD"
  },
}
```